# Optimize Oracle to Parquet Spark Write

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, etl

Super new to Spark so trying to learn with this simple task I've inherited.

The task is to pull data from an Oracle database (using partitioning) and then write it to an S3 compatible storage as a Parquet file.

In a nutshell the code looks something like this:

```
val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", jdbcUrl)
.option("dbtable", "(select * from table1 where c1>0)")
.option("partitionColumn", "partition_col")
.option("lowerBound", "1")
.option("upperBound", "9999999")
.option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
.load()

df.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("s3a://location")
```

Spark configs are:

```
    "spark.speculation": "false"
    "spark.kryoserializer.buffer": "256m"
    "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max": "2047m"
    "spark.hadoop.mapreduce.outputcommitter.factory.scheme.s3a": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.commit.S3ACommitterFactory"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.name": "directory"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.committer.staging.conflict-mode": "append"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multipart.size": "256M"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multipart.threshold": "256M"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.block.size": "256M"
    "spark.sql.sources.commitProtocolClass": "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.PathOutputCommitProtocol"
    "spark.sql.parquet.output.committer.class": "org.apache.spark.internal.io.cloud.BindingParquetOutputCommitter"
    "spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles": "true"
    "spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead": "LEGACY"
    "spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite": "LEGACY"
    "spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy": "LEGACY"
    "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions": "200"
    "spark.default.parallelism": "200"
    "spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload": "true"
```

The spark job takes about an hour and a half to run and I'm trying to figure out if there's anyway to reduce that time.
The resulting table is about 800GB, and I've made sure the chosen partition_col is indeed uniformly distributed. For now I don't really care the size/# of files for the resulting parquet, I'd just like to finish writing the parquet ASAP.

Currently the cluster is fixed to have:
20 executor instances
2 cores per executor
80GB per executor

Some observations - I've noticed that there are a handful of long running tasks even though they seem to be writing the same relative amount of data as the other tasks.  Does anyone have any idea what's happening here? See:
https://i.imgur.com/HXOZCbE.png

If anyone has any suggestions to optimize this, it would really be appreciated!

So far I've tried toying around with differing partition columns and numPartitions from 80 to 1000 but it seems stuck at around 90 minute mark regardless.
I've also tried setting the fs.s3a.fast.upload to true but to no avail

Comment: If you are unleashing 200 or 1000 concurrent sessions to Oracle to pull your data, you're almost certainly overwhelming its storage I/O capacity and hitting a wall. Make sure the # of concurrent threads is modest (I'd say no more than 10). That's not going to make your job run faster, but it will hopefully prevent you from causing significant degradation for others using the same database or other databases using the same storage array. Also ensure that the column you use is the partitioning key in Oracle itself. If the table isn't partitioned in Oracle, it should be.

Comment: the s3a committers all print their statistics into the _SUMMARY file; you can take a look at that to get their view of the actual commit process. if the delays are query side then that's a different problem.  w.r.t fs.s3a.fast.upload the slow upload was removed years ago, and the s3a committers do special tricks anyway. try asking for a smaller cluster with more cores to see if that makes a difference as the s3a output stuff does parallelise block uploads if it can -but it needs the CPU time